# Select all cells with value from specific row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy all cells with value in it from 2nd row 'coz 1st row is the heading/title. However, my code seems to select ALL cells with value. :(
Here's my code to copy:

```
Dim myData As Workbook
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xlsx")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

Comment: [resize it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

Comment: personal preference of course, but might want to remove your name from that file path...

Comment: @MacroMan no one would've noticed until you pointed it out =P

Comment: @findwindow still, better me than an annoying recruitment spam person/thing.

Comment: @MacroMan don't flatter yourself. No one is more annoying than _you_ =P Edit: I am so troll XD

Answer (score 6):

Even though you have mentioned `CurrentRegion` in your code, I suspect you do not need it or at least are not planning to use it in the intended way

Let's say our worksheet looks like this. Notice the formulas in Col F?

[image]

The problem with using `.Resize` is that it will include cells which has formulas even if they return blank values.

Taking MacroMan's example

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

> I'm trying to copy all cells with value in it from 2nd row 'coz 1st row is the heading/title.

From what I understand, what you want can be achieved by finding the last row and last column **which has data** and copying that.

I think this is what you want? Notice the use of `LookIn:=xlValues` with `.Find`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

        lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

        Debug.Print rng.Address
        rng.Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This would be my preferred method instead of`.CurrentRegion` +1

Comment: I tried this & it works perfectly when copying from the same workbook. I guess I forgot to specify that I'm copying from a different workbook.

Comment: You can copy to different workbook using this as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to offset and resize:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy
End With
```

Comment: Nice one.. there is a slight problem with this. If your data is till say 5th row and the Row 2 to 10th row has formula in it then it will copy till the 10th row :). This will happen even when the formula returns a blank value

Comment: This worked! Just had to change .Copy to .Select.. Thank you so much! @MacroMan